# How to navigate JSON Object in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I made this webservice that handles my database functions, and this is an AJAX call to one of the methods.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Service/dataBaseService.asmx/getRMAData",
        data: '{"RMAId": 1 }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert(data.RMA_ID);
        }
  });
```

this is what is logged:

```
({d:"[{\"RMA_ID\":1,\"RequestDate\":\"2013-02-28T00:00:00\",\"Company\":1,\"Status\":\"Accepted            \",\"Serial\":201764,\"LastChangeDate\":\"2013-02-28T00:00:00\",\"LastChangeBy\":\"Foreign    \",\"Price\":null}]"})
```

However `alert(data.RMA_ID)` returns undefined aswell as `data.d.RMA_ID`?

How can I get hold of the values?

Comment: Are the `(...)` really part of the response? Looks like broken JSONP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `data` that you've logged is an object with a property named `d`, that contains a string value. You could probably make adjustments at your server side to make the value of `d` an object rather than a string, but the way it is currently constructed, you would be able to parse it into an object using `JSON.parse`.

Once you've done that, the resulting object should be an array, containing one single object. Thus, your access to `RMA_ID` would be as follows:

```
var data = JSON.parse(data.d);
alert(data[0].RMA_ID);
```

Comment: +1 deleting my answer because I had not initially realized that the value of `d` is a string, rather than an already-parsed object.

Comment: Thank you David, i am fairly new at this. I took a look at my serverside and made it return objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using simple javascript you need to parse JSON response

```
var resp = eval('(' + data + ')');
```

or thru jQuery

```
var resp = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

now you can access the data using '.' and key name

```
console.log(resp.d[0].RMA_ID)
```

Comment: `eval` is disencouraged, `JSON.parse` is not really jQuery and no, `resp.RMA_ID` won't be defined either way.